# Django runscript: no such table

Tags: python, django

I have a problem using `runscript` from the `django-extensions`. I followed the instructions and created a directory `scripts` with `__init__.py` and the following script `test.py`

```
from portal.apps.base.models import Country

def run():
    e = Country.objects.get(pk=1)
    print e
```

The model import seems to work fine. However, trying to get data from that model leads to

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: base_country
```

although `base_country` exists.. I tried to import a model that doesn't exist just to make sure that the import works, and if I import nonsense such as `from portal.apps.base.models import blabla`, runscript can't even locate the script.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you run **manage.py syncdb** or **manage.py migrate** before? Did it create the base_country table?

Comment: The table exists as a mysql database. If I run manage.py syncdb and manage.py migrate django creates a sqllite db.. There might be something wrong with my settings..

Comment: Yes, you should check the database configuration on the DATABASES variable of the settings.py file